# How to make a sticky div float over the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a floating menu sticky to the top of the window, and occupying only 1/4 of its width. The remaining 3/4 (as well as behind the menu's 1/4) should be occupied by the image on the next document section. However, the image initially appears below the menu, i.e. the menu is not floating as I want it to.

What I'm getting:

[image: problem]

What I want:

[image: solution]

```css
body,ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
header {
  background: green;
}
nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
main img {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' />
</main>
```

How do I make the sticky element float all the time, i.e. display no white space on its right side?

EDIT: The image cannot be on the background. It should be inside the `main` tag, where there will be more elements, including text and possibly other images. It all should scroll together, except for the menu, that must stick to the top.

Comment: The difference between sticky and fixed is that sticky sticks to the current position and fixed is always fixed. To achieve what you want you will need to do a fixed positioning and add a top value of your header height. You can achieve this without any javascript if you set a static height of your header.

Comment: @THEAMAZING Please read my comment on Prajwal's answer. For this approach I need JavaScript because the header is not fixed, thus its visible height changes on scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider float and shape-outside trick to make sure the element will take no space:

```css
body,ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
header {
  background: green;
}
nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  float:left;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(transparent,transparent);
}
main img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' />
</main>
```

Another idea is to consider a `height:0` wrapper

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background: green;
}

nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  height:0;
}

main img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>
<div class="nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<main>
  <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' />
</main>
```

Comment: Your snippet still shows whitespace to the right of the `<nav>`.

Comment: @Rodrigo can you show me a screenshot of that space? I don't see any space

Comment: @Rodrigo check again, you were probably testing with Firefox. Update the value of shape-outsie so it works on Firefox

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Yes, I'm using Firefox. Isn't it following the W3C specification in this case?

Comment: Or is it Chrome/Chromium which doesn't follow the W3C specification?

Comment: @Rodrigo it's not really about the spec here but the use of the 100% ... the correct value is the one I have used noe. Before I was using `100%` instead of `0 0 100% 0` which is equivalent to `100% 100% 100% 100%` and may lead to unexpected result

Comment: According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/), "A pair of insets in either dimension that add up to more than the used dimension (such as left and right insets of 75% apiece) define a shape enclosing no area. For this specification, this results in an empty float area." And "An empty float area (where the shape encloses no area) has no effect on line boxes." Meaning that `inset(100%)` should have no effect at all. Thus, the correct command seem to be `inset(0 0 100% 0)`. However, it doesn't work on Chromium.

Comment: @Rodrigo what version are you using? It's working fine on my end. I can try something else than inset. There is a lot of different values that will produce the same result

Comment: I'm running Chromium 83.0, but that's not the main point. The main point is that users will be using different versions of different navigators, and I need a solution that will work for most of them. By now, the JavaScript version is working better, which is (again) a shame for CSS.

Comment: @Rodrigo it should work fine since the support is good: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_shape-outside (only the dead IE will fail). Check the update, I used a different value less ambiguous

Comment: The updated value still doesn't work on Chromium. By the way, Chromium is not listed on `caniuse.com`.

Comment: @Rodrigo technically Chromium should almost have the same support as Chrome ... maybe you need to enable some settings for shape outside. check `layout.css.shape-outside.enabled`

Comment: This should be at `about:flags` (Chromium equivalent of `about:config`)? It's not.

Comment: @Rodrigo added another idea without shape-outside

Comment: Right, CSS is the world of hacks. Finally a hack that works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is possible with `position:sticky`. Because `sticky` is supposed to get allocated with the `static` positioned elements in case of no scolling.

I guess you will have to do this yourself using JS. You can optimise the way it is getting hidden & using proper transitions it shouldn't be of an issue.

This is from MDN -

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the
> document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor
> and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including
> table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and
> left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky

.

.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (window.scrollY > 25) {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('sticky');
  }
});
```

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background: green;
}

nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  position: fixed;
}

nav.sticky {
  top: 0;
}

main img {
  height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' />
</main>
```

Comment: That's almost working, except that the menu should follow the header in the first 25px of scrolling.

Comment: @Rodrigo you can manually add the `top` position for nav based on `scrollY`.

Comment: Yes, it works. However, [MDN itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects) recommends against it: `This constant moving and snapping will result in a jittery visual effect. One way to implement this without the scroll event listener is to use the CSS property designed for this purpose`. I'll wait to see if a pure-CSS solution appears.

Comment: @Rodrigo Better approach would be to push the title bit later along with the nav change state. This way, you can avoid multiple paints.

Comment: Didn't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use background css property. You could make use of position absolute to your image tag or if your intention is to use the image as background then consider using background properties, below i have pasted a sample codevto use background image and a link to the background properties usuage.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background: green;
}

nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

main img {
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
top: -55px;
}
```

```html
   <header>Title</header>
  
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg" />
</main>
<p>
This is a sample text
</p>
```

Comment: Actually, the image is part of the page. There will be some text below the image, and the image should disappear to the top of the page, when scrolling to read it all.

Comment: I have update my snippet, please check and this may not be an actual solution, may be this gives some idea, play around with position property. hope this helps your query.

Comment: This way I need to know the height of the `<nav>` beforehand. If the user changes the size of the font (zooming in or out), it may break.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
header {
  background: green;
  /* changes */
  height: 5vh;
}
nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  /* later changes*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
}
main img {
  width: 100vw;
  /* changes */
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' />
</main>
```

Comment: The menu should stick to the top.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set the position of the image to `position : absolute;` Then move it to the desired location.

Since the item will no longer stick, we can make an empty `div` element.
Also, place the image before your navigation (can also use `z-index` property in CSS).

```css
body,ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
header {
  background: green;
}
nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  position: sticky;
  top : 0;
}
main img {
  width: 100vw;
  height : 300px;
  /* add z-index */
  z-index : -1;
  /* change position */
  position : absolute;
  top : 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' />
<!-- create new div to replace image -->
<div style = "width : 100vw; height : 300px;">
</div>
<span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>
</main>
```

Comment: 1) The image height shouldn't be informed, so as not to stretch it. 2) I added some paragraphs to `<main>`, after the image, but couldn't see them.

Comment: The height was set just to show the scroll. Since the image position is now absolute, any items added after the image must go after the div. Also, set the height of the div to the image height.

Comment: If you absolutely need to add elements to `<main>`, I edited the snippet by adding the div into `<main>` and set the `z-index` of the image to -1.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use z-index for the img and nav
2. alternate, you can create div like a div i've creates with opacity:0;
   for fake overflow;

may help

edited:

1. img position :relative because you want an img trigger
2. i've set your id of your elements id DOM name
3. i have been calculated your nav height is 65, i take this img top automaticaly
4. don't judge me i'm just tryna help.
5. thank you

```js
  function SetTop() {
   
    var a = document.getElementById("nav").offsetHeight;
    var b = document.getElementById("img");
    // this 0 because top of img overlapping the "sticky position"
    b.setAttribute("style", "top : "+(0-a)+"px");
  }
```

```css
body,ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
header {
  background: green;
/* you need height for position top of img */
}
nav {
  background: #ff000080;
  width: 25vw;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

z-index: 1;
}
main img {
  /* this top need a height from a header */
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
   
div {
 color: black;
 }
```

```html
 <body onload="SetTop()"/>
  <header>Title</header>
    <nav id="nav">
     <ul>
       <li>link 1</li>
       <li>link 2</li>
       <li>link 3</li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
  <main>
    <img src='https://cdn.britannica.com/90/3890-050-F451C580/rainforest-coast-lowland-rainforests-Ecuador-tropics-evergreen.jpg' id="img" />
  </main>

   <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: The text is supposed to go after the image, not over it.

Comment: This "sticky" need an element which {position: relative;} or except absolute triggered. if you want to an <img> as a trigger, you can change <img> {position: relative} then do a top of <img> equal into <nav> height, this need script.js to calc your <nav> height.. but i'll try

Answer (score -1):

just use-- position: sticky; in css to make div sticky

Comment: If you read my CSS, you'll see I'm already doing that.

Comment: he is already using position as `sticky`. You can play around with the code snippet he added (just click on `Copy snippet to answer`), and see if you can come up with a solution.